# How to remove blank pages from PDF using PDFSHarp?

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

How will i be able to remove a blank page from a PDF file? I have a sample PDF file where the 1st page contains a few strings and a 2nd page with absolutely NOTHING in it. I tried to loop into the pdf pages and get the element count PER page but the funny thing is that i get the same number between the 2 pages =| How did that happen if the 1st page has a few strings and the 2nd page was absolutely blank???

This is my code

Dim inputDOcument As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open("")
Dim elemountCount As Integer = 0
Dim elemountCount2 As Integer = 0
Dim pdfPageCount As Integer = inputDOcument.PageCount

For x As Integer = 0 To pdfPageCount - 1
            elemountCount = inputDOcument.Pages(x).Contents.Elements.Count
            elemountCount2 = inputDOcument.Pages(x).Elements.Count
Next

Answer (score 4):

Try to check length of each element:

```
public bool HasContent(PdfPage page)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < page.Contents.Elements.Count; i++)
    {
        if (page.Contents.Elements.GetDictionary(i).Stream.Length > 76)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why Stream.Length > 76?

Comment: Hi, @dadde is there any update on this?

Comment: @MaidenlessRunt no sorry I'm still clueless

Comment: I chose 76 at random. Empty page contains invisible elements of small size. If there are no big elements then I consider this page as empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the PDFsharp Document Explorer that comes with PDFsharp to see what the PDF file really contains.
Or load and save the file with a PDFsharp DEBUG build, this will give you a "verbose" file. Viewing that with Notepad could help to understand what the file contains.